# R programming using the cut() function to split a variable into 3 classes

Tags: r

I a have a dataframe called `wine` with variables among which is the variable
`Spice` of integer type. I would like to split this variable (`Spice`) using the `cut()` function into 3 classes ( <2; between 2 and 2.5; >3 ).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean spice is numeric (and not integer, which would only fall between 2 and 2.5 if it was exactly two), it might be hard to do with just cut if you're trying to be left and right inclusive.

You can get close with something like

```
dat <- data.frame(spice=5*runif(100))

dat$lvl <- cut(dat$spice, breaks=c(0,2,2.5,1e6), right=FALSE)

dat$lvl <- as.factor(as.numeric(dat$lvl))
```

though if the value for spice is exactly 2.5 it will be placed in group 3 instead of group 2.

Comment: `as.factor(as.numeric(...))` is a bad idea, because you'll end up with factors with strings of numbers for labels, which is a perfect storm for confusing bugs. Better to leave the default labels from `cut` (which are more descriptive, anyway), or add unique ones with the `labels` parameter. You can also use `Inf` instead of `1e6`, which will make it look a little better.